# Punkbuster support on Windows 8 developer preview

Tags: punkbuster

I was wondering if there is any way to modify the registry or whatever to allow Punkbuster to accept Windows 8 developer preview as a legitimate build of Windows?

This is required for me to be able to play Battlefield 2142 and I've tried some of the old methods back when Vista betas were being release but to no avail.

Comment: It's a _dev preview_, not OS replacement... you should still have your `insert-current-os-here` installation and be using that as your primary OS for everyday gaming and whatnot.

Comment: I know I know, but dev preview or not, it is not the os that is causing punkbuster to deny privelages; but punkbusters internal code that decides wether an operating system is legit or not.

Comment: All I'm saying is that you really shouldn't be doing any serious gaming on Win8. Evenbalance will add support if and when they decide to update. You shouldn't expect much more from a preview except that you may have to wait for your apps get supported.

Comment: I'm not expecting anything, merely wondering if such a possibilty exists;If I know /why/ it isn't supported. But I also remember vista beta days when there were workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 is still a restricted, incomplete and unreleased version of Windows. At this time Evenbalance have not incorporated support for the latest version of Windows which will result in errors such as the following when playing games that require Punkbuster whilst using Windows 8;

> ```
> "Unknown Windows Api Function"
> "Disallowed Program/Driver"
> ```

Currently there is no work around for this issue, it is likely that the situation will be similar to that of the Windows 7 release, in that Evenbalance will make no changes to Punkbuster to resolve the issue until the new version of Windows is ready for release.

For the time being the only workaround would be to reinstall Windows 7, or install Windows 7 to a separate partition specifically for playing games that require Punkbuster.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that there is no support for Windows 8 Release Preview.  Are you sure this still valid?

Comment: Source: [PunkBuster is also currently not compatible with Windows 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PunkBuster#Incompatibilities).